# Xamarin TestCloud timeout defaults

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I am writing UITests and can't find the default values for the timeouts. Does anyone know how long the default timeouts are both locally and on Xamarin TestCloud?

I have tried Google, but havent had any luck.

Did I understand correctly that if I change them that I overwrite both local and cloud values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, UITests waits up to **15 seconds** for tests running locally, and **one minute** for tests running in App Center before throwing the TimeoutException. If you specify a different wait time, that will override the default, and apply to both local & App Center tests.

If you want to change the timeout.

```
app.WaitForElement(c=>c.Marked("success_message_label"),
                   "Did not see the success message.",
                   new TimeSpan(0,0,0,90,0));
```

For more details, please see this thread.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/features/timeouts

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue